# Why gcc emits unneeded memory accesses when passing trivial struct by value?

Tags: c++, assembly, arm, calling-convention

It's known that some small structs with no non-trivial copy-ctor and no non-trivial dtor are passed in registers.

Quoting [ARM Procedural Call Standard](https://www.google.pt/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi_u6mRwevJAhWBnBQKHXkiC-IQFggeMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Finfocenter.arm.com%2Fhelp%2Ftopic%2Fcom.arm.doc.ihi0042e%2FIHI0042E_aapcs.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEHpeQK4nXulfVer9lozrR3IXZLtQ&sig2=7nVtav6x4MEBDH4pdsoVTg):

> Fundamental types larger than 32 bits may be passed as parameters to, or returned as the result of, function calls.
>   When these types are in core registers the following rules apply:
>   
>    A double-word sized type is passed in two consecutive registers (e.g., r0 and r1, or r2 and r3). The content of
>   the registers is as if the value had been loaded from memory representation with a single LDM instruction.

And indeed, I can easily confirm this with clang. gcc however emits a bunch of memory loads and stores for such a simple code snippet:

```
struct Trivial {
    int i1;
    int i2;
};

int foo(Trivial t)
{
    return t.i1 + t.i2;
}
```

---

```
$ clang++ arm.cpp -O2 -mabi=aapcs -c -S && cat arm.s

add r0, r0, r1
bx  lr
```

---

```
$ g++ arm.cpp -O2 -mabi=aapcs -c -S && cat arm.s

sub     sp, sp, #8
add     r3, sp, #8
stmdb   r3, {r0, r1}
ldmia   sp, {r0, r3}
add     r0, r0, r3
add     sp, sp, #8
bx      lr
```

I'm using the gcc and clang supplied by ArchlinuxARM distro, running on raspberry pi 2 (gcc 5.2), but I've also reproduced it with gcc based cross-compilers.

Comment: Try again with  `-O3`

Comment: Sounds like a _missed optimization_ type bug in gcc. @M.M FYI, it's the same with `-O3`

Comment: That's a bit disappointing... I expected it to do better than that.

Comment: When gcc copies a struct with byte members, for example, it doesn't do it with a single wide load/store.  It copies the bytes separately.  (This was a regression years ago and still hasn't been fixed.  A quick search didn't find the bug report for it, sorry).  This is may be another symptom of gcc's failure to fully understand structs.

Comment: That is disappointing.  I might have understood across translation units.

Comment: testing with compiler explorer -- the x64, ARM64 and AVR versions of gcc all do optimize this code correctly, just the 32-bit ARM version doesn't

Comment: does gcc 4.x produce the same code?  and 3.x?

Comment: 4.8 does the same thing at least the C compiler does

Comment: Interesting. I observe the same for armv7-m, but when compiling for armv6-m I got properly optimized code. So, if I compile that way: "arm-none-eabi-gcc -mthumb -march=armv7-m -nostdlib -O2 main.c" I see your issue. But when compiling "arm-none-eabi-gcc -mthumb -march=armv6-m -nostdlib -O2 main.c" the code is more or less like the one you've got from clang. So, for ARMv6-M it seems that ABI is utilized in a better way. Also, I don't see differences in this case between O2, O3 and Os.

Answer (score 2):

This has been confirmed as a gcc bug [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69008), now we wait.